# Помогите разобраться с логами ошибки

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Добавил в приложение статистику от Flurry и обнаружил что часто возникают ошибки.

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x181666950 <redacted> + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x18db6c1fc _objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                      0x181666890 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
3   Foundation                          0x182113180 -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:] + 264
4   <тут название приложения>                         0x1000adef8 __mh_execute_header + 302840
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x18e144014 <redacted> + 24
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x18e143fd4 <redacted> + 16
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x18e1471dc __dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 336
8   CoreFoundation                      0x18162662c <redacted> + 12
9   CoreFoundation                      0x18162496c <redacted> + 1452
10  CoreFoundation                      0x1815656d0 _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
11  GraphicsServices                    0x187249c0c _GSEventRunModal + 168
12  UIKit                               0x184696fdc _UIApplicationMain + 1156
13  <тут название приложения>                         0x1000905f8 __mh_execute_header + 181752
14  libdyld.dylib                       0x18e15faa0 <redacted> + 4
```

Помогите разобраться, ничего не понял из этих логов. В какую сторону копать? [NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:] ?

Comment: проверь значение, которое хочешь сохранить в `NSUserDefaults`, возможно там `nil`

Comment: nil для NSUserDefaults допустимое значение, проверь, везде, где сетишь в юзер дефалтс, что именно туда попадает и когда

Comment: выяснил, что эта проблема встречается только у iPhone 5S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Статья по этой теме на хабре [Демистификация аварийных журналов iOS](http://habrahabr.ru/post/167805/)

Comment: Почитал статью, спасибо:)
Там сказано что [NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:] + 264 значит: ошибка на 264-ой строке. Но нигде у меня нету setObject'а на этой строчке.

Comment: У меня не много опыта по этой теме, но это не номер строчки вашего кода) Вот тут есть инфа http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287074/how-to-get-correct-line-numbers-in-symbolicated-crash-reports-iphone-mac